# Can I make this dplyr + data.table task faster?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I guess this is more of a `dplyr` than `plyr` question. For the sake of speed I am using `data.table` in some code I have written. During an intermediate step I have a table with some genomics data with ~32,000 rows:

```
> bedbin.dt
Source: local data table [32,138 x 4]
Groups: chr

   bin   start           site chr
1    2 3500000         ssCTCF   1
2    3 4000000 ssCTCF+Cohesin   1
3    3 4000000         ssCTCF   1
4    4 4500000         ucCTCF   1
5    4 4500000 ssCTCF+Cohesin   1
6    4 4500000 ssCTCF+Cohesin   1
7    4 4500000 ssCTCF+Cohesin   1
8    4 4500000         ssCTCF   1
9    4 4500000         ssCTCF   1
10   5 5000000         ssCTCF   1
.. ...     ...            ... ...
```

**EDIT**

Or the first hundred lines of data like so (thx to Ricardo Saporta for instructions)

```
bedbin.dt <- data.table(structure(list(bin = c("2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4","4", "5", "5", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "8", "8", "9", "9","11", "12", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "14", "15","15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "15", "16", "16","17", "17", "17", "18", "20", "20", "20", "21", "21", "21", "21","21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "21", "22", "22", "5057", "5057","5057", "5057", "5059", "5059", "5059", "5059", "5059", "5060","5060", "5060", "5060", "5060", "5060", "5061", "5063", "5063","5064", "5064", "5064", "5064", "5064", "5064", "5064", "5064","5064", "5064", "5064", "5064", "5064", "5064", "5064", "5064","5064", "5064", "5064", "5064"), start = c(3500000L, 4000000L,4000000L, 4500000L, 4500000L, 4500000L, 4500000L, 4500000L, 4500000L,5000000L, 5000000L, 6000000L, 6000000L, 6000000L, 6000000L, 6000000L,6000000L, 6500000L, 6500000L, 7000000L, 7000000L, 8000000L, 8500000L,9500000L, 9500000L, 9500000L, 9500000L, 9500000L, 9500000L, 9500000L,9500000L, 10000000L, 10000000L, 10000000L, 10000000L, 10000000L,10000000L, 10000000L, 10000000L, 10000000L, 10000000L, 10500000L,10500000L, 11000000L, 11000000L, 11000000L, 11500000L, 12500000L,12500000L, 12500000L, 13000000L, 13000000L, 13000000L, 13000000L,13000000L, 13000000L, 13000000L, 13000000L, 13000000L, 13000000L,13500000L, 13500000L, 162500000L, 162500000L, 162500000L, 162500000L,163500000L, 163500000L, 163500000L, 163500000L, 163500000L, 164000000L,164000000L, 164000000L, 164000000L, 164000000L, 164000000L, 164500000L,165500000L, 165500000L, 166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L,166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L,166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L,166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L, 166000000L), site = c("ssCTCF","ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF+Cohesin","ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin","ssCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF","ucCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF","ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin","ssCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF+Cohesin","ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF","ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF","ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF","ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF","ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF","ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF","ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF","ucCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF","ucCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ssCTCF","ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ssCTCF", "ucCTCF","ucCTCF", "ssCTCF+Cohesin", "ucCTCF", "ucCTCF", "ucCTCF"), chr = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 20L,20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L,20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L,20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), .Label = c("1","10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "2","3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "X"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("bin","start", "site", "chr"), sorted = "chr", class = c("data.table","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L)), key='chr')
```

**END EDIT**

I next want to create all possible combinations of each row versus every other (grouped by chr). This would form a query(join) onto some other data so I'm thinking best (and simplest) to precompute :

```
# grouped by chr column
bedbin.dt = group_by(bedbin.dt, chr)

# an outer like function
outerFun= function(dt)
  {
   unique(data.table(
    x=dt[rep(1:nrow(dt),each =nrow(dt)),],
    y=dt[rep.int(1:nrow(dt),times=nrow(dt)),]))
  }

> system.time((outer.bedbin.dt = do(bedbin.dt, outerFun1)))
   user  system elapsed 
 90.607  13.993 105.536
```

To my mind this is sloooowwww...although relatively compared to using `data.frame`, or base functions like `by()` or `lapply()` it is quite a lot quicker. However this is actually a smallish dataset I am testing it on.

So... I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas about a faster version of outerFun??? Is there a faster way than `rep()` or `rep.int()`?

Comment: hi, can you please post a reproducible example? -- you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here: http://bit.ly/SORepro   -  [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://bit.ly/SORepro)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, Hi I'm not sure how I can post a fully reproducible example. Let me think on that. Perhaps I can make code to create it first?? One moment please...

Comment: have a look at the link I posted.  you can simply use `reproduce(bedbin.dt, rows=100, cols=c("bin", "start", ..etc))`

Comment: it's not clear exactly what you're doing, but it looks like you just might be looking for the `CJ` function?

Comment: So you want a cross-join? Can you explain why? Normally you don't want to combinatorially explode the amount of data you have.

Comment: it's complicated... another much larger table of genomic data is keyed by columns bin1 and bin2. This larger table holds the the data values of interest which are measurements of relation/distance between points. So yes there is really is a combinatorial explosion. I'm using dplyr here so that the larger table can go into sqlite because in some cases it won't fit in RAM. The code above though wil fit in RAM always so I think this is a reasonable approach (Hmmm... maybe).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Ricardo pointed out, it sounds like you simply want this:

```
bedbin.dt[, CJ(1:.N, 1:.N), by = chr]
```

Comment: I think you should store that in a variable say, `tt` and then do: `cbind(dt[tt$V1], dt[tt$V2])`, not sure though.

Comment: Hi on the test data this gives a different answer (5288 rows) to my own function (1936) - and not all the columns I want. However CJ does look like a promising function.... but I am really weak on data.table syntax I need to go and google some till I appreciate exactly what is going on here. thx.

Comment: @StephenHenderson sorry, I can't install `dplyr` and am not sure what that code does - this was my best guess at it - `CJ` is about the same `expand.grid` btw

Comment: @eddi yeah I think it's close to what I want then and a bit quicker.. but I don't think it's 1:.N as for instance there is no bin = 1 in the original data but there is in your answer. So I can use what you have done - didn't know about CJ() - but just need to gen up on the syntax to solve it myself. thx again

Comment: @StephenHenderson, it might help if you take a small data and show us the output you desire.