# Pulling data from a different data.frame with dplyr?

Tags: r, plyr, data-manipulation, dplyr

I have a data frame called dat_new, essentially it is clinic visit data, hrn being a patient ID, and dov being date of visit (multiple visits per person). Then I have a data frame called event with dated hospital admissions (multiple admissions per person).

What I want to do, is for each clinic visit, I want to sum the hospital admissions that occurred prior to that clinic visit, simple.

This works with ddply from plyr, takes a bit of time but works well.

```
temp <- ddply(dat_new, .(hrn,dov), summarise,
              dka2 = sum(event$event_code[which(event$hrn==hrn & event$doa <= dov)]==2),
              dka3 = sum(event$event_code[which(event$hrn==hrn & event$doa <= dov)]==3),
              dka8 = sum(event$event_code[which(event$hrn==hrn & event$doa <= dov)]==8)
)
```

Now, trying to rewrite in dplyr, I get an error

```
Error: binding not found: 'event_code'
```

I have it coded like this:

```
temp2 <- group_by(dat_new, hrn, dov)
temp3 <- summarise(temp2,
                   dka2 = sum(event$event_code[which(event$hrn==hrn & event$doa <= dov)]==2))
```

Obviously event_code is not in the temp2 data frame. Is it a case of dplyr can not work with 'other' data frames when 'summarising'? If there is a far better way to be doing the 'lookup'/sum I'm doing I'm all ears.

I did try this a few times trialing loading packages on a vanilla R in different orders to try and eliminate any namespace issues.

Thanks

EDIT - REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

This is a quick and dirty example just to illustrate the issue. If we make a 'lookup' data.frame that has 2 of each car, with a mpg around 500, we can then try and go through the original data.frame, looking up in the new data.frame and summing the two mpgs together. plyr gives the expected, figures around 1000. dplyr errors.

```
# add the model names as a column so they're easier to get at
mtcars$models <- row.names(mtcars)

# create a 'lookup' table
xtra <- data.frame(models = rep(row.names(mtcars),2),
                    newmpg = rnorm(2*nrow(mtcars),500,10)
)
xtra <- xtra[sample(row.names(xtra)), ]

library(plyr)
ddply(mtcars, .(models), summarise,
        revisedmpg = sum(xtra$newmpg[models==xtra$models]) )
# great, one row per car, with both mpgs added together
library(dplyr)

temp2 <- group_by(mtcars, models)
temp3 <- summarise(temp2,
                   revisedmpg = xtra$newmpg[models==xtra$models] )
# error
```

Comment: I experienced similar issue two few weeks ago and I think this is related to https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/170 . I do hope that there's an elegant way to achieve this kind of task using `dplyr`. Looking forward to see the answer to this question. You question is really intersting so please make some effort to make it reproductible if you people to help you. Use the `mtcars` data set for example.

Comment: Okay done, as crude as it is :)

Comment: Thks. Let hope that a `dplyr` guru will find a workaround now.

Comment: I think what you want here is a cross join, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552104, which dplyr doesn't currently support. This is the third time this problem has come up so I'll think about it for a future release, https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/197.

Comment: Perhaps @hadley. It's probably a poor choice of words but I prefer to think of this (my current working plyr version) as more of a lookup than any sort of join. As I eluded to in the comment on Troy's answer below, I don't like the idea of a 'join' given you get n1 x n2 records in the resulting data frame/table (that is then manipulated).

Comment: A lookup is just a type of join. I think we're just using different language for the same thing.

Comment: Fair enough :) I meant 'poor choice of words' on my part btw.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
merge(mtcars,xtra,by="models") %.% group_by(models) %.% summarise(sum(newmpg))
```

**EDIT** sorry I think this is what you want;

```
# from what I can tell of your data:
dat_new<-data.frame(hrn=c("P1","P2"),dov=42000)
event<-data.frame(hrn=sample(dat_new$hrn,20,T),doa=41990+sample(1:20,20),event_code=sample(2:8,20,T))


merge(dat_new,event,by="hrn") %.%
filter(doa<=dov) %.% 
group_by(hrn,dov) %.%
summarise(dka2=length(event_code[event_code==2]),
          dka3=length(event_code[event_code==3]),
          dka8=length(event_code[event_code==8]))

Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
Groups: hrn

  hrn   dov dka2 dka3 dka8
1  P1 42000    2    1    0
2  P2 42000    1    0    1
```

And apologies - I'd mixed up doa & dov before the edit - you may need to tweak the `merge(,by=c("x",..))` call depending on what else is in your tables

Comment: Or you could use `dplyr::inner_join()` ;)

Comment: Thanks Troy. So this gets the job done, and is quicker than plyr on my dataset (I have about 15k records in dat_new and 900 in event). I'm not too keen on merging the two as a first step though. A subject with 25 records in one and 15 in the other ends up with 375 in the merged dataset. So while it's still quicker, it has a real counter-intuitive/sloppy feel to it. No offense obviously! This may be the best we have for now! Also the output isn't identical, plyr's output has the same number of rows as dat_new, this solution drops those where all (dka2/3/8) are 0.

Comment: V crude testing has inner_join running about 3 times faster than merge for this solution on my data @hadley